# run npm scripts to deploy to s3

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, npm

I have a simple express app which renders some config for the client bundle to use:

```
    const config = config.get('client'); 

    const HTML = `
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="client"></div>
        <script>
          window.config = ${JSON.stringify(config)}
        </script>
        <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
    `;

    res.status(200).send(HTML);
```

For production I want to host a static version of this on AWS s3. I want a static version of the html above with both the stringified `config` and the webpack `bundle.js` including the hash.

For this I think I need a small express server that pulls in a templated version of the html above which will get populated with the config and the webpack bundle name and then written as `index.html` in the `dist` folder.

I intend this script to be run from an npm script:

```
scripts: {
  build-html: node render-static.js,
},
```

Once this has run the next step would be to upload it to an s3 bucket so that would require another node script that would need to run. I might end up with a final `npm run deploy` that runs:

```
npm run build-html && npm run-deploy-static
```

I'm not sure if there is a better / more accepted way of doing this sort of thing? Is it correct to be running two node scripts in order to be deploying a part of my app?

Comment: Maybe  html-webpack-plugin and the s3-plugin-webpack are the right plugins for the job?